# Python web scraping results not showing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am quite new to web scraping so would appreciate some guidance!
I want to print the results of a google name search, but nothing is showing. I figured out that the for loop `for result in search_div:`isn't being executed, so maybe no results are being identified by the program? My code is as follows:

```
from googlesearch import search
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print('Please enter your first name')
firstName = input()
print('Please enter your surname')
secondName = input()
query = firstName + ' ' + secondName
print('Please enter language ex:[en,fr,ar,jp,cn...]: ')
lang = input()

# requests
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?hl={}&q;={}&start;=3i#=10&ie;=UTF-8'.format(lang, query)
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}#headers
# url source
source = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

# BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
# find all divs that contain search result
search_div = soup.find_all(class_='rc')
for result in search_div:
    # loop result list
    #geting h3
    print('Title: %s'%result.h3.string)
    print('\n')
    #geting a.href
    print('Url: %s'%result.a.get('href'))
    print('\n')
    # description
    print('Description: %s'%result.find(class_='st').text)
    print('\n###############\n')
```

And I get 'Process finished with exit code 0'. I would greatly appreciate help with this!

Comment: That is probably because you don't have anything in `search_div`. Try to use `soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")` instead ?
Also use `mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "rc"})` to find divs with specific classes.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML document `requests` sees and the DOM that you see in your browser are different. This is because `requests` does not execute Javascript, while your browser obviously does. Download the HTML and check to see if the elements you need are present. If not, you can use `requests-html` which does execute Javascript.

https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you haven't specified a proper element as [Leogout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63265399/python-web-scraping-results-not-showing#comment111872556_63265399) mentioned. If you don't want to specify element to tag, use [`select()` or `select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) `bs4` methods which accept `CSS` selectors, e.g:

```py
soup.select('CSS_SELECTOR')     # equivalent to find_all()/findAll()
soup.select_one('CSS_SELECTOR') # equivalent to find()
```

You can write directly in the `input()` e.g:

```py
input('Please, enter your hero name: ')
```

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Organic-results#main.py):

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
  'User-agent':
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

query_input = input('Please, enter your hero name: ') # entering John Cena

params = {
  "q": query_input,
  "hl": "en"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params).text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
  url = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
  snippet = result.select_one('.lEBKkf').text
  print(f'\n{title}\n{url}\n{snippet}\n')

--------
'''
Please, enter your hero name: John Cena

John Cena - Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Cena
John Felix Anthony Cena is an American part-time professional wrestler, actor, television presenter, and former rapper currently signed to WWE.


John Cena - IMDb
https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1078479/
John Cena, Actor: Bumblebee. John Felix Anthony Cena was born on April 23, 1977 in West Newbury, Massachusetts to Carol Cena and John Cena.
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do it as well by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your particular example is that you don't need to figure out what was the problem of the script, all that needs to be done is to iterate over structured JSON and get what you want without doing extracting part.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

query_input = input('Please, enter your hero name: ')

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google",
  "q": query_input,
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
  title = result['title']
  url = result['link']
  snippet = result['snippet']
  print(f'\n{title}]n{url}\n{snippet}\n')

-------------
'''
Please, enter your hero name: John Cena

John Cena - Wikipedia]nhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Cena
John Felix Anthony Cena is an American part-time professional wrestler, actor, television presenter, and former rapper currently signed to WWE.


John Cena - IMDb]nhttps://www.imdb.com/name/nm1078479/
John Cena, Actor: Bumblebee. John Felix Anthony Cena was born on April 23, 1977 in West Newbury, Massachusetts to Carol Cena and John Cena.
'''
```

P.S - I wrote a bit more detailed blog post about how to scrape [Google Organic Search](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-organic-search-with-python-3hp5).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.